# SQL Measuring the difference between two days

Tags: mysql, database

So I'm using the Northwind Database for a project, and one part involves writing a query to that returns values when the difference between the OrderDate and RequiredDate is greater then 28 days

I'm getting 0 rows returned so I think I'm wrong but I can't tell how I'm wrong.

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, RequiredDate
```

FROM Orders
WHERE (OrderDate - RequiredDate) > 28

Answer (score 0):

MySQL DATEDIFF function calculate the number of days between two DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values.

In your case :

```
DATEDIFF(OrderDate, RequiredDate) > 28
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DATEDIFF` as

```
DATEDIFF(OrderDate,RequiredDate) > 28
```

Remember your field should have a datatype of `DATE` or `DATETIME` in order to make it working